# Setting up multiple instances of Cognos on server

Tags: tomcat, multiple-instances, cognos

We have been trying to configure three instances of Cognos on a windows server machine. For some reason we can only run one instance at the time.

We did follow these instructions: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.cognos.inst_cr_winux.10.1.0.doc%2Finst_cr_winux_id5772RunningReportNetandCognosSeries8.html

And we could not resolve this issue.

Can anyone provide any advice?

Thank you

Comment: What error or issue do you get when you try and start a second instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you reinstall the product when adding a new instance. Put it in a new directory.

In IIS, create a new application pool + new virtual directory wich points to new Cognos WebContent directory

In new virtual directory, create new application and name it cgi-bin wich points to cgi-bin directory of new WebContent directory. Make sure it uses the new application pool you created in previous step

In mapping manager for cgi-bin, add a new script mapping to point to cognosisapi.dll from new cgi-bin directory.

In Cognos Configuration, make sure you change every paths to where you put the new installation

Change default port 9300 to something else. Change other default ports for something unique and unused (except for port 80 if this is what is used for this installation)

Also in Cognos Configuration, change the applications.xml path to make sure it points to new installation

And lastly, make sure Content Store, Logging, Audit, etc. databases and every other databases used by new Cognos instance have been created and used only for new instance.

Good luck!

Comment: You will also want to change the Shutdown Port (under the IBM Cognos Service section) and the Logging Port (under the Logging section) settings.  The product will function without these alterations, but this can cause issues with logging going to the wrong place, and shutdown behaviour can sometimes be erratic.